# Instagram find Hashtag by Name API

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, hashtag

I'm building an Instagram hashtags finder app and I'm looking for a way to get Instagram hashtags by name along with other similar hashtag suggestions and their post counts.

I read about the Instagram API endpoint:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=snowy&access_token=XXXX

but this old Instagram API platform is deprecated and cannot see a similar endpoint on the new Graph API.

Also, if there is any way to do this without having the user to login to Instagram that would be preferred.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am in the same boat with not knowing the new endpoints to get user data

Comment: I've been searching all day for this and cannot find any way to get the hashtags by name and their suggestions...

Comment: i would suggest you start converting to the instagram graph api on facebook for developers it looks like that will be our only way out because ive been sitting with a broken app since Monday and still havent found anything i decided to wait for my review submission to be approved on facebook for developers then ill start using the new endpoints

Comment: @TjLaubscher Yes but we only get limited access to hashtags with that new endpoint... :/ ah Instagram and Facebook are turning into paid ad platforms only but little do they know that they need people to advertise to in order to keep operating...

Comment: i made a work around for this all i did was change the endpoint api for instagram to this [@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" + id + "/media/recent/?access_token=" + accessToken] and then let the users generate an access token and then u can start pulling in data again :)

Answer (score 1):

Hashtag id search endpoint in v1 API is deprecated [1] and it has moved to Facebook's Graph API [2]. As long as you have an Instagram user id and an access token for that user you can use Facebook Graph Explorer [3] to query that endpoint.

[1] https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog

[2] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-hashtag-search

[3] https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: What exactly do you write in the graph explorer to get hashtag suggestions and count? It seems like there is no endpoint for that.