# Facebook/Instagram API - Getting Popular Hashtags

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to use the Instagram API for one of my projects. The task I'm trying to accomplish is getting popular hashtags based on an input keyword.

To elaborate a bit: when you're on Instagram, and start typing a hashtag, you get a popup with suggested hashtags related to what you're typing, sorted by popularity.

I'm trying to get these suggestions, but through an API call. Looking at the Instagram API docs, there is `Hashtag Search` [as shown here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/hashtag-search/), but this endpoint searches for posts which use the input hashtag, which is not what I want.

[Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53694612/instagram-find-hashtag-by-name-api) suggested I have a look at Facebook Graph API instead, but again no luck there either.

I know this is possible to do as certain websites which provide services to schedule posts, like [this one](https://later.com/) do it.

So, is there an endpoint in either Instagram or Facebook API that I've missed, or is there any third party API / tool that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently any "trending" features as part of Instagram Graph API.